# Como não permitir gravação se radios criados dinamicamente não estiverem marcados

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando fazer uma validação para que somente seja permitido a gravação dos registros se todos os `radios` estejam marcados, sejam para `Sim` ou para `Não`, estou criando os `radios` de forma dinâmica mas o código que fiz para tentar essa validação não está funcionando, como pode ser visto a seguir.

O botão que dispara a ação está assim:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Finaliza">
    Gravar
</button>
```

O script que fiz:

```js
document.getElementById("Finaliza").onclick = function() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("Status[]");
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].unchecked) {
            alert("Você precisa selecionar o status");
        }
    }
};
```

A criação dos radios estão assim:

```php
<p>
 <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="Status[]<?php echo $IdItemCheckList; ?>" value="1"> Sim
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="Status[]<?php echo $IdItemCheckList; ?>" value="0"> Não
 </label>
</p>
```

Comment: Acho que a razão é o `getElementsByName`. Você está usando `.getElementsByName("Status[]")`, enquanto os `inputs` possuem nome de `Status[]<?php echo $IdItemCheckList; ?>`, ou seja, `Status[]Qualquercoisa` é diferente de `Status[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o `getElementsByName("Status[]")` já que nenhum dos inputs terá o nome `Status[]`, assumindo que o `<?php echo $IdItemCheckList; ?>` não retorne vazio. Basta que crie um novo atributo/classe e utilize ele no lugar do `getElementsByName`.

---

Entretanto, uma solução mais fácil... Se ambos possuem o mesmo nome (e neste caso é o mesmo `$IdItemCheckList`), basta que adicione o `required`, isso fará com que o navegador impeça o `submit`.

```html
<form>
  <div>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[]A" value="1" required> Sim
   </label>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[]A" value="0" required> Não
   </label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[]B" value="1" required> Sim
   </label>
   <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="Status[]B" value="0" required> Não
   </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Finaliza">
      Gravar
  </button>   
</form>
```